# Looping in R while generating row number, not column value

Tags: r, loops

I'm having trouble generating the value in column "hospital". When I loop the function it churns out the row number, rather than the hospital name.

Here's a small example: I made a .csv file with 4 columns and 3 rows (including the title). I listed the column title:values. Only Hospital.30 is numeric:

```
hospital_name: hospital1, hospital2
Hospital.30: 12,4
death:heart, heart
State: A A
```

The goal is to sort the hospitals from lowest "Hospital.30" to highest. So the goal is to have hospital2, then hospital1.

And here is my code:

```
best <- function(states, source, id=1:2) {
    framework <- read.csv("hospital/example.csv")
    hospital_name <- "hospital_name"
    death_source <- "Hospital.30"

    mortality_list <- framework[which(framework[, "State"] == states), death_source]
    hospital_list <- framework[which(framework[, "State"] == states), hospital_name]
    numeric_mortality <- as.numeric(mortality_list)
    x <- rep(0, length(id))  # x is the column with numeric death count
    y <- rep(0, length(id))  # y is the column with the names of hospitals
    for (i in id) {
        x[i] <- sort(numeric_mortality, partial = i)[i]
        y[i] <- hospital_list[numeric_mortality == x[i]]
    }
    print(x)
    print(y)
}
```

So when I try and run this in the console:

```
best("A", 1:2)
```

I get:

```
[1]  4 12
[1] 2 1
```

2 1 are the row numbers associated with the sorted x values I got, but I defined the loop for the column "hospital_name".

How do I make it show `hospital2 hostpital1` instead of `2` `1`?

`dput(head(framework))` is this:

```
structure(list(hospital_name = structure(1:2, .Label = c("hospita1", 
"hospita2"), class = "factor"), Hospital.30 = c(12L, 4L), death = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = "heart", class = "factor"), State = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor")), .Names = c("hospital_name", 
"Hospital.30", "death", "State"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Could you describe in words the purpose of the function, and also share `dput(head(framework))` so we can see what the data looks like?

Comment: No! The `dput()` output is perfect.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: The [coursera tag got burninated.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274845/1757964) Please don't use it any more.

Comment: @Cerbrus, by whose authority? I still see it has tag-wiki and that it wasn't deleted

Comment: Let's not discuss that on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is data types. When you initialize `y<-rep(0,length(id))`, you're defining `y` as a numeric. Your `hospital_list` is a factor, which has both a numeric representation (2, 1, indicating the levels) and a character representation (indicating the labels). The easiest fix is to just convert `hospital_list` to character. Replace it's definition with this:

```
hospital_list <- as.character(framework[which(framework[,"State"] == states), hospital_name])
```

and your problem will go away.

As a side note, your `which` is unnecessary, you can shorten to

```
hospital_list <- as.character(framework[framework[,"State"] == states, hospital_name])
```

Comment: I was looking into as.character( but couldn't figure out where it would go. Thanks a ton. I've been learning a lot and you guys have been a ton of help :)

Comment: @AndrewYueh happy to help! A (marginally) better way to initialize vectors is by specifying the type and length, e.g. `integer(3)`, `numeric(10)`, or in this case `character(length(id))`.